# How to integrate Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributables and DirectX into the Windows image by using the Windows ADK?

Tags: windows, drivers, directx, adk

I'am about to build my own `Windows 10` imgage. What I've done so far:

I use the following directories:

- `D:\Windows\drivers` folder with drivers for my system
- `D:\Windows\extracted` folder with the extracted source image
- `D:\Windows\mount` folder for the created image
- `D:\Windows\wim` folder for the `Windows 10` file `install.wim` .

The workflow:

1. Copy `install.wim` from `D:\Windows\extracted\sources` to `D:\Windows\wim`
2. Download the latest (for your system) [Windows ADK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/get-started/adk-install) and install at least the following [components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/windows-deployment-scenarios-and-tools#windows-assessment-and-deployment-kit):

   ```
    Deployment Tools
    Imaging And Configuration Designer (ICD)
    User State Migration Tool (USMT)
   ```
3. Start `cmd` (press `Windows+X` start `Windows PowerShell (Administrator)` and type `cmd`)
4. Disable all (programs/custom services) you can
5. All commands following now are for the `cmd`:

   ```
    SET DISM="C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\amd64\DISM\dism.exe"
    %DISM% /Mount-Wim /WimFile:"D:\Windows\wim\install.wim" /index:1 /Mountdir:"D:\Windows\mount"
    %DISM% /Image:"D:\Windows\mount" /Add-Driver /Driver:"D:\Windows\drivers\bluetooth\Rtkfilter.inf"
    %DISM% /Image:"D:\Windows\mount" /Add-Driver /Driver:"D:\Windows\drivers\HDMI Audio\AtihdWT6.inf"
    %DISM% /Image:"D:\Windows\mount" /Add-Driver /Driver:"D:\Windows\drivers\network\rt640x64.inf"
    %DISM% /Image:"D:\Windows\mount" /Add-Driver /Driver:"D:\Windows\drivers\touchpad\AsusTP.inf"
    %DISM% /Image:"D:\Windows\mount" /Add-Driver /Driver:"D:\Windows\drivers\chipset\GPIO2\amdgpio2.inf"
    %DISM% /Image:"D:\Windows\mount" /Add-Driver /Driver:"D:\Windows\drivers\chipset\I2C\amdi2c.inf"
    %DISM% /Image:"D:\Windows\mount" /Add-Driver /Driver:"D:\Windows\drivers\chipset\PSP\amdpsp.inf"
    %DISM% /Image:"D:\Windows\mount" /Add-Driver /Driver:"D:\Windows\drivers\chipset\SATA\amd_sata.inf"
    %DISM% /Image:"D:\Windows\mount" /Add-Driver /Driver:"D:\Windows\drivers\chipset\SMBus\SMBUSamd.inf"
    %DISM% /Image:"D:\Windows\mount" /Add-Driver /Driver:"D:\Windows\drivers\chipset\UART\amduart.inf"
    %DISM% /Image:"D:\Windows\mount" /Add-Driver /Driver:"D:\Windows\drivers\video" /Recurse
    %DISM% /Image:"D:\Windows\mount" /Add-Driver /Driver:"D:\Windows\drivers\WLAN\netrtwlane02.inf"
    %DISM% /Image:"D:\Windows\mount" /Add-Driver /Driver:"D:\Windows\drivers\audio" /Recurse
    %DISM% /Image:"D:\Windows\mount" /set-productkey:YOUR-WIN-DOWS-KEY-HERE
    %DISM% /Unmount-Wim /Mountdir:"D:\Windows\mount" /commit
    %DISM% /Cleanup-Wim
   ```

Now I wish to include some [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist). I need (because of some old games):

- [Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 x86](https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/6/B/16B06F60-3B20-4FF2-B699-5E9B7962F9AE/VSU_4/vcredist_x86.exe) ,
- [Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 x64](https://aka.ms/highdpimfc2013x64enu) and the current
- [Microsoft Visual C++ 2015, 2017, 2019, and 2022 x86](https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vc_redist.x86.exe) and
- [Microsoft Visual C++ 2015, 2017, 2019, and 2022 x64](https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vc_redist.x64.exe) and the old
- [DirectX 9.29.1974.1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8109).

Is it possible to integrate the above libraries into the Windows image with `DISM`? If yes, how can one do this?

Comment: Two things: (1) Windows 10 is getting inexorably nearer to end of life to invest this kind of energy in it; and (2) Apps use Visual C++ libraries and have a habit of updating Visual C++ libraries when the Apps update.  Perhaps use caution of how much energy you pour into this.  DirectX also seems to be more a function of major Windows versions (need Win 11 for newest DirectX)

Comment: "If yes, how can one do this?" - At the most basic level, install everything you want, then run [sysprep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/sysprep--generalize--a-windows-installation?view=windows-11) then create an image using DISM.

Comment: Hello @John! Thank you for your comment! Like I wrote in my question: I need the **old Visual C++** libraries and the **old DirectX** for **old games**. There weren't any updates for a long time now and there probably will no updates anymore. Furthermore this games don't work on `Windows 11` (maybe I'am doing something wrong). This why I will leave one computer with `Windows 10` for old stuff. For this reasons I don't need the latest updates of `Visual C++` and `DirectX`, except of `Visual C++ 2015, 2017, 2019 and 2022`, because this came as a boundle and will receive updates in future too.